# Судак и судачить: однокоренные ли слова?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Судачить: сплетничать, обсуждать что-то. Думаю, что оно родственно слову "пересуды". Но при чем тут тогда рыба судак? Или это просто похожие слова, ничего общего между собой не имеющие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фасмер  предполагает,  что  судак ( рыба ) это  древнее  заимствование  из  немецкого  через  польский.  Значит  судачить  и  судак  не  однокоренные,  а  просто  схожие  слова.